# Prioritizing prefabs in array for procedural generation

Tags: unity, mathematics, procedural-generation, random, procedural

I am trying to create procedural space background with a bunch of sprites of nebulas and stars. I have made few prefabs with different types of sprites attached to them. I have created an array through which game will loop and randomly place different stars on a background.

The question is. I want for example 90% of white stars in the background and 10% of others. I know I can create few loops for each prefab with a different maximum number, but it doesn't look very efficient. Is there any way to prioritize some array items while looping through an array?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decide your total star count. Divide it into segments. For example, out of 100 total stars:

- 10 Blue Star Hard
- 30 White Star Medium
- 60 Red Star Soft

Code:

```
//can make enum StarColour
int BLUE = 0;
int WHITE = 1;
int RED = 2;

//can make enum StarFocus
int HARD = 0;
int MEDIUM = 1;
int SOFT = 2;

int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < blueHardTotal; i++)
{
    PlaceStar(BLUE, HARD);
} 

for (i = blueHardTotal; i < blueHardTotal + whiteMediumTotal; i++)
{
    PlaceStar(WHITE, MEDIUM);
} 

for (i = whiteMediumTotal; i < whiteMediumTotal + redSoftTotal; i++)
{
    PlaceStar(RED, SOFT);
}
```

This takes you through index `[0]` to `[99]` in segments. P.S. There is nothing inefficient about this; and if you make the `Total`s compile-time constants, then the compiler should unroll the loops, thereby avoiding all conditionals.

If you want a more elegant way:

```
int[,] totals; //index in here by colour and focus, e.g. totals[RED, SOFT]

int i = 0;
for (int c = 0; c < COLOUR_COUNT; c++)
{
    for (int f = 0; f < FOCUS_COUNT; f++)
    {
        int max = i + totals[c, f];
        while (i < max)
        {
            PlaceStar(c, f);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you expand with this int[,] totals; and enums thing? I do not completely understand how can I create such array and mark each item with enums.

Comment: @NikitaDemidenko `enum` in C# is just a group of `int` under the hood. Every `enum` entry has a corresponding integer value, assigned from 0 upwards. You can easily cast the `enum` to an `int` e.g. `int med = starFocus.Medium;` and even back again. So in that sense it's exactly the same as using a group of pre-defined constants like I have above, but it gets to have a name and its own grouping - a bit like a C# namespace, really. Do a little research on stackoverflow and you'll understand.